# Counting subsets with large sum

Tags: co.combinatorics, upper-bounds

Suppose that you have a multiset of positive integers $I$.

$I$ is not given, but it is known that the sum over all elements of $I$ = $k$.

(e.g. if $I$={2,5,7} then k=14 is given, but I is unknown).

We are also given another integer $r$.

$S\subseteq I$ will be called $r-minimal-subset$, if $sum(S)>r$,

and for every $x\in S$, $sum(S$\{x}$) \leq r$.

For example, if $I$={1,3,3,5,7,8} and r=10,

then {3,3,5} and {1,3,7} are r-minimal-subset, but {5,7,8} is not (as the subset {7,8} 's sum is 15. {7,8} is a r-minimal-subset).

What is the the best upper bound we can give on the number of $r-minimal-subsets$ of I?

(In this setting, we get is $(r,k)$, while $I$ is being chosen by an adversary).

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit:
Hmm, sorry for the question.

Obviously the answer is $k \choose r+1$, for I={1,1,..,1}, $|I|=k$.
It doesn't let me answer the question, so you could go ahead :/.

Answer (score -1):

Let me know if I understood the question correctly: you want to count the sets of $n$ positive integers summing exactly $k$, right? This is $\binom{n+k+1}{k}$. If you want for non-negative integers version, add one more number to the count, $\binom{n+k+1}{k+1}$.

Comment: No, that's not what s/he's trying to compute.